# How to implement watermarking of images in YII framework?

Tags: image, yii, watermark

I want to watermark images at the time of uploading in yii.

Please anyone help me to do that.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site not a free code-writing service. Please show details of what you've tried and why it isn't working.

Comment: I tried many codes for that, but all are unsuccessful. So just asked a question.

Comment: "I tried many codes" doesn't tell us _what_ you tried or where you went wrong. You'll need to post details of what you've tried along with details of any errors or incorrect behaviour that resulted. Please see [this help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information on how to ask a good question on Stack Overflow, and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for guidelines on what to include when asking a question about code that isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write your own code for that just google "php watermark images" or something similar. You can find many examples here as well like:
[Image watermarking in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593837/image-watermarking-in-php)
[php watermark and save image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220343/php-watermark-and-save-image)

If you just want to use Yii extension for that just google "yii watermark" for example. It gave me this extension url:
https://github.com/zhdanovartur/yii-easyimage